# unable to setTimout on .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently im trying to set a page so that on click of a button one div `.animates` up and another `.animates` down in the place the old div was which has been successful. The problem is they both do this at the same time making the animation a bit messy. What I want to do is have the animation pause for about 2 seconds just after the first div has moved up and then bring down the second div. Here is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.aboutcontainer,.contactcontainer,.homecontainer,.portfoliocontainer,.musiccontainer').hide();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".homecontainer").show();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#about').click(function go() {
        $('.homecontainer,.musiccontainer, .portfoliocontainer, .contactcontainer').fadeOut({
            queue: false,
            duration: 'slow'
        });
        $('.homecontainer, .musiccontainer, .portfoliocontainer, .contactcontainer').animate({
            'margin-Top': "-1000px" //moves left
        });
        $('.aboutcontainer ').fadeIn({
            queue: false,
            duration: 'slow'
        });
        $('.aboutcontainer').animate({
            'margin-Top': "115px" //moves left
        });
    });
});
```

I have tried inserting a `.delay(2000)`just before the `.fadeIn` here:

```
 $('.aboutcontainer ').fadeIn
```

and another one before the `.animate` here:

```
 $('.aboutcontainer').animate
```

`.delay` does not seem to work at all (im using the lates `jQuery` version)

The weird thing is I have tried using a `setTimeout()` function like so:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.aboutcontainer ').fadeIn({
        queue: false,
        duration: 'slow'
    });

    $('.aboutcontainer').animate({
        'margin-Top': '115px' //moves left
    });
}, 2000);
```

When I do the `.fadeIn` pauses for the 2 seconds but the `.animate` does not. Can someone please let me know what im doing wrong here?

Comment: can you post a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) with your HTML and script.

Comment: he is right, me too once tried but cant make it

Comment: What is incorrect in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwjq8wj3/)?

Comment: couldnt ge tthe fiddle to quite work so posted this:http://benliger.webatu.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At [your site](http://benliger.webatu.com) `.aboutcontainer` has `margin-top: 115px;` at main.css:131.

So animation from `margin-top: 115px;` to `margin-top: 115px;` actually does nothing.

You can set, for example, `margin-top: -1000px` for `.aboutcontainer` and see the animation in action.

Comment: Thank you so much, quite embarrased at how simple a mistake this was!  Was driving myself crazy... I've still found that .delay() didnt work for me which remains a mystery

Comment: @BenLiger you're welcome. About `delay` - you can make it work by setting `queue: true` in `fadeIn` (like in this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwjq8wj3/1/)), but it prevents executing of `fadeIn` and `animate` simultaneously.

Comment: @BenLiger just on more comment: you can actually use `delay` with `queue` to make them work simultaneously: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwjq8wj3/2/)

Comment: ok, could you give me an example of how this could work in my code?

Comment: @BenLiger you can use `delay` with `queue` like in [mentioned fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwjq8wj3/2/): just replace `otherDiv` with `$('.aboutcontainer ')`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the time paramater for animation, 
Try to add the timing for animation like below.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.aboutcontainer ').fadeIn({
        queue: false,
        duration: 'slow'
    });
        $(".aboutcontainer").animate({
            marginTop: "115px",
        }, 750);//Look at here..
}, 2000 );
```

here is the jsfiddle, check it http://jsfiddle.net/ganeshgaxy/d6g1empb/

Comment: And please take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6g1empb/1/) without animation duration. Do you see any problems? I don't... Maybe the speed of animation is a little different, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: its still giving me the same problem with adding in the time parameter. Ive created a fiddle here but can't get it to display as my site does (sorry im a bit new to this) so not sure if it will help:http://jsfiddle.net/donejs/qYdwR/

Comment: ive put my site live on a free host to better show my problem:http://benliger.webatu.com/

Comment: excuse me what is in your site, i'm not getting it, which is creating the problem

Comment: hey @BenLiger Your site has one error, Its `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mozilla' of undefined`

Comment: hmmm so when I click the button .fade pauses for the required time but the .animate seems to fire straight away. Are you saying thats not the case with you? Will look into that error now

Comment: yes your site has that error, that's what preventing the other codes like setInterval(), i can't see your sites scripts, otherwise i will help you. So clear that error, or check where you use the word `mozilla`

Comment: ok apparently if i add <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script> it will fix that. adding now

Comment: why do you use migrate?? what are all the plugins you are using?

Comment: think thats fixed the error, could you try now and let me know please?

Comment: for jquery:: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
for migrate:: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js

Comment: i just quickly googled a solution. I only use jquery UI and 1.11

Comment: the firefox error message is gone but my initial problem still persists

Comment: and also still your webpage showing this warning, but it is not a problem, i think.`JQMIGRATE: Logging is active jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:21
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:41
console.trace() jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:43
migrateWarn`

Comment: Thanks for your help Ganesh, the problem was that the container was originally set to margin-top:115 instead of -1000 which is of course why i wasn't seeing any animation